# PTIJ: What's so special about Cola?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It says in Bireishis 24:1 Hashem blessed Avraham Bakol.
Targum Onkoles tiches Bakol to mean Bicola. With Cola. Why was Cola such a blessing?
Also we praise Hashem in Brich Shimeh. אנת הוא שליט על כלא.
He has control over Cola.
What's so special about Cola?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Actually just heard yesterday that the midrash says Avraham named his daughter Bakol

Answer (score 9):

Because it comes from a Divine source.

Many a tzaddik in the period of the Gemara was zoche to hear a בת קלא (e.g. [Kesubos 77b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.77b.8?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) - a Heavenly voice, or to the trained ear, the ‘psssssssssssssssssssch’ of an ice cold can of coke being opened in the heavenly realm.

Ultimately, it is synonymous with holiness.

Indeed, Shabbos a day of elevated ruchniyus taps into this mindset. We stop the humdrum world of work to engage in more spiritual pursuits. The [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 72](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.72.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) observes that this marks a special time to grab yourself some coke:

> וְאָמְרוּ רַבּוֹתֵינוּ זִכְרוֹנָם לִבְרָכָה, **שקולה** שַׁבָּת כְּכָל הַמִצְוֹת
>
> And our Rabbis of blessed memory said that Cola on Shabbos is like all the mitzvos.

Answer (score 8):

As we see in Psalm 29, cola has many good attributes:

> קול ה' על המים... קול ה' בכח קול ה' בהדר: קול ה' שובר ארזים... קול ה' חוצב להבות אש: קול ה' יחיל מדבר... ...קול ה' יחולל אילות
>
> Cola is over the water... Cola is power, Cola is majesty. Cola breaks cedars... Cola kindles flames of fire. Cola convulses the wilderness... Cola causes hinds to calve...

(Based on Sefaria's translation)

So we see that cola has all of these special characteristics (to be honest, I don't even fully understand all of them). Because Cola is so special, it's a very noteworthy b'racha, and it's a praise hashem is worthy of.

Answer (score 4):

With regards to @Dov's reference to the pssssshhhh sound of opening a coke can, for those who don't know, the IDF often uses buses called "[tiyuliyot](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA#:%7E:text=%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA,%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99%D7%AA%22%20%D7%90%D7%95%20%22%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA%22.)", largely to transport soldiers to shooting ranges. Soldiers in Basic Training often have to be ready to jump out ASAP as soon as the doors open. This is called "the Pepsi Procedure" (נוהל פפסי) because the doors make a sound like opening a can of Pepsi. In other words, Hashem's blessing to Avraham was to be a successful warrior (much like his success in the War of the Four and Five Kings), but He referred to Cola because it's better than Pepsi (the IDF doesn't splurge on Cola for newbies). Nothing but the best for Hashem's favorites. Likewise, the term "He has control over Cola" is related to "Hashem Tzeva'ot" and "Hashem is a Man of War"; terms that signify the might of Hashem.